# How to change a color for a 1 symbol in string?

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView, and I need to change a color for a 1 symbol from the TextView. I have made it already, but I forgot how it is possble. There is specia class for working with strings - it possible to change a color, to underline the text, etc. Please, tell me this class. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

```
  final SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder();
   ....
  result.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(redColor), result.length() - 1, result.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
   ....
  recognitionText.setText(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. Please, tell me, how can I underline the 5 symbols from text? Thank you again

Comment: Look for the subclasses of: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html